# how to capture desktop using vc++

Tags: visual-c++, desktop, screen, capture

I am trying to capture desktop. i found some code which capture the desktop , but takes some time.

```
void CSDITESTView::OnFileTest()
{
int nScreenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
int nScreenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);

HWND hDesktopWnd = GetDesktopWindow()->m_hWnd;

HDC hDesktopDC = ::GetDC(hDesktopWnd);
HDC hCaptureDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hDesktopDC);
HBITMAP hCaptureBitmap =CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDesktopDC,nScreenWidth, nScreenHeight);
SelectObject(hCaptureDC,hCaptureBitmap); 
BitBlt(hCaptureDC,0,0,nScreenWidth,nScreenHeight, hDesktopDC,0,0,SRCCOPY|CAPTUREBLT); 
::ReleaseDC(hDesktopWnd,hDesktopDC);
DeleteDC(hCaptureDC);
}
```

But i need code which capture quick and save it as image.

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: I don't know why this would take too long. How long, exactly, and which line of code is the slowest?

Comment: I need to record the desktop actions in to video. But the above code takes 2 or 3 seconds for capturing single image. so when i am continuously use the code to capture image , the system get hangged. I am looking for a code which captures with out taking any time. Please guide me to the correct path.

Comment: Have you tried creating the bitmap at the start and re-using it rather than creating it every time?

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code using performance counter functions, as follows:

```
void CMainFrame::OnTestTest()
{
   LARGE_INTEGER lFreq, lStart, lEnd;
   ::QueryPerformanceFrequency(&lFreq);
   ::QueryPerformanceCounter(&lStart);

   /// BEGIN BENCHMARK ///
   int nScreenWidth = ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
   int nScreenHeight = ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);

   HWND hDesktopWnd = ::GetDesktopWindow();

   HDC hDesktopDC = ::GetDC(hDesktopWnd);
   HDC hCaptureDC = ::CreateCompatibleDC(hDesktopDC);
   HBITMAP hCaptureBitmap = ::CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDesktopDC,nScreenWidth, nScreenHeight);
   ::SelectObject(hCaptureDC,hCaptureBitmap); 
   ::BitBlt(hCaptureDC,0,0,nScreenWidth,nScreenHeight, hDesktopDC,0,0,SRCCOPY|CAPTUREBLT); 
   ::ReleaseDC(hDesktopWnd,hDesktopDC);
   ::DeleteDC(hCaptureDC);
   /// END BENCHMARK ///

   ::QueryPerformanceCounter(&lEnd);
   double dTime = ((double)lEnd.QuadPart - lStart.QuadPart) / lFreq.QuadPart;
   // ..
}
```

The resulted time was about **80 microseconds**. 
I don't think your computer is incredible slow. Probably the problem is in another side (e.g. a matter of thread synchronization).